# How to show that $\cos(x_0)\leq \cos(x)+(x-x_0)\left[\sin(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)}{2}\right]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How to show that $$\cos(x_0)\leq \cos(x)+(x-x_0)\left[\sin(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)}{2}\right]$$ where $x$ is a variable and $x_0$ constant?

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Use Taylor's expansion for $\cos x$ at $x=x_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Consider the function 
$$f(x)=\cos(x)+(x-x_0)\left[\sin(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)}{2}\right]-\cos(x_0).$$
Then 
$$f'(x)=-\sin(x)+\sin(x_0)+(x-x_0)\quad \text{and}\quad f''(x)=-\cos(x)+1\geq 0$$
and we may conclude that $f$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}$.
Now note that $f(x_0)=0$, $f'(x_0)=0$. Show that $f(x)\geq 0$ that is $f$ has a minimum point at $x_0$.